# Ceph pool deleted but files remain in list

Tags: ceph

I filled up my OSDs through Rados-gw, and the only thing I could do to get Ceph working again was delete the pool that was taking up all the room, and recreate it.  Nevertheless, when I list the contents of all pools (using `boto`), it shows all the files that were there (the disk space is freed, so those files no longer exist in reality.)

What's causing this inconsistency?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you only deleted the buckets pool, typically **.rgw.buckets**, then that would explain why you still have the list of all the objects.

The index pool takes care of the list of objects. You would also need to delete the **.rgw.buckets.index** pool as well. Make sure you stop your gateways before doing this as well.

When you start the gateway back up and create a new bucket then the index pool will be recreated (if the rgw auth has wrx permission to the monitor).